# Build clang on windows with cmake, WinMain reference undefined

Tags: c++, windows, clang, mingw-w64

i'm trying to build clang with mingw-w64 on windows (10), so i followed this tutorial : https://here-be-braces.com/blog/llvm-clang-on-windows-mingw-revisited 
but cmake don't recognise gcc as an C++11 compiler. I run cmake with this command :

```
cmake C:\llvm -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_BUILD_TOOLS=ON -DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=ON -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-IC:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -DGCC_INSTALL_PREFIX=%syspath% -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%syspath% -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-lmingw32 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lstdc++ -lm -lpthread  -lgcc -lmsvcrt -lmoldname -lgcc_eh -lkernel32 -luser32 -ladvapi32 -liconv -lmingwex" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DLLVM_PARALLEL_COMPILE_JOBS=2 -DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=2 -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -DGCC_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/mingw64" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="C:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib"
```

I obtened the list of librairies with "gcc -v test.c -Wl,--verbose", test.c is just an classic hello world. But with the libmingw32, I get this error :

> cmd.exe /C "cd .  && C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -lmingw32 -static-libgcc
>   -static-libstdc++ -static -lstdc++ -lm -lpthread -lgcc -lmsvcrt -lmoldname
>   -lgcc_eh -lkernel32 -luser32 -ladvapi32 -liconv -lmingwex
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_3b639.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTC_3b639.exe
>   -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_3b639.dll.a
>   -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -lkernel32 -luser32
>   -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32
>   -ladvapi32 && cd ."
>
> CMakeFiles/cmTC_3b639.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj:testCCompiler.c:(.text+0x0):
>
> multiple definition of `main'
>
> C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x0):
>
> first defined here
>
> C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e):
>
> undefined reference to `WinMain'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Without it, i get further, but i get this : http://pastebin.com/zeMViHzA

> CMake Error at projects/libcxx/CMakeLists.txt:423 (message):
>
> C++11 or greater is required but the compiler does not support c++11

How can i get rid of the "WinMain undefined reference" for the cmake tests ?

edit : the gcc version : 6.2.0

Comment: which version of gcc?

Comment: `WinMain` is used by programs for the "windows" subsystem (programs with a windows message loop). `main` is used for the "console" subsystem. Maybe you need to change the target to "console"?

Comment: The problem is that i can't change the test code from cmake